# Fill an image with pre-defined pattern with Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, composite, wand

I have an image (like that: [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcu7J.png)) and two integers, which represents a final image width & height. According to Wand's documentation [Open empty image](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/guide/read.html#open-an-empty-image):

```
with Image(width=200, height=100) as img:
    img.save(filename='200x100-transparent.png')
```

It will result in an empty image with transparent background.
Now, the question is: How to create a same empty image, but with *mask* image as background pattern?

The `composite` CLI command itself has a following operator:

`-tile                repeat composite operation across and down image`

But how to achieve the same with Wand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after looking on ImageMagick's Composite [source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/df0b2915c254e43ac809a58d5bba39e57d16012e/MagickWand/composite.c#L192) itself, it became clear, that the Wand-driven solution should look like:

```
with Image(width=x, height=y) as img:
    for x in xrange(0, img.width, crop_mask_path.width):
        for y in xrange(0, img.height, crop_mask_path.height):
            img.composite_channel('default_channels', crop_mask_path, 'over', x, y)
    img.save(filename='patterned_image.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building out the title iterator is [the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426682/438117) in my opinion. However another *hackish* method would be to invoke the `tile:` protocol, and allow the internal ImageMagick methods to handle composites. You'll lose the control inherited by DIY, but gain some performance on optimized IM systems.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

with Image() as img:
   # Same as `-size 400x400' needed by tile: protocol.
   library.MagickSetOption(img.wand, 'size', '400x400')
   # Prefix filename with `tile:' protocol.
   img.read(filename='tile:rose.png')
   img.save(filename='tile_rose.png')
```

[image: pre defined pattern with wand]